# Gradle keeps running and can not find symbol R in offline

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle, java

I am having issue in my project with gradle, it keeps running, i have tried to work in offline mood then i am facing cannot find symbol R issue.

I turned on "offline work" by

```
File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle > offline work
```

Gradle version which i am using is 2.14.1.

In my build.gradle file i am using

```
      compileSdkVersion 24
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 24


      Output of ls -l
          total 40
          drwxrwxr-x 5 adnan adnan 4096 Nov 11 10:38 app
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan  625 Nov 10 17:43 build.gradle
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan  861 Nov 10 17:46 danielx.iml
          drwxrwxr-x 3 adnan adnan 4096 Nov 10 17:43 gradle
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan  855 Nov 10 17:43 gradle.properties
          -rwxrwxr-x 1 adnan adnan 4971 Nov 10 17:43 gradlew
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan 2314 Nov 10 17:43 gradlew.bat
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan  497 Nov 10 17:44 local.properties
          -rw-rw-r-- 1 adnan adnan   15 Nov 10 17:43 settings.gradle
```

I have attached screenshoot of SDk Manager.

[image]

Any hint would be great help.

Comment: Did you check if Android Studio is able to make network connection in background? Make sure the network and proxy configurations are correct. Second thing, from Android studio Terminal try to resolve the project dependencies with this command "gradlew --refresh-dependencies" ( in mac "./gradlew --refresh-dependencies"). It should give you some info if there are any issues.

Comment: i have applied command " gradlew --refresh-dependencies" and m receiving message
" 
No command 'gradlew' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gradle' from package 'gradle' (universe)"

Comment: And then i tried " gradle --refresh-dependencies"" and message is 
The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gradle

Comment: In your project directory can you see a file named as "gradlew.bat". I think it should be available. Please note that the command has to be executed within the terminal available in Android studio, not from Command Prompt (PC) or terminal (mac).

Comment: I have tried that command in android studio termial.

Comment: In your project directory can you see a file named as "gradlew.bat" ?

Comment: Yes i can see that file "gradle.bat", after installing gradle i tried comman gradle --refresh-dependencie" and got this message after too much jar downloading , 

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Minimum supported Gradle version is 2.14.1. Current version is 2.10. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /home/adnan/Matrix_Projects/danielx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127808/discussion-between-addy-and-paul).

Comment: have you tried cleaning and building the program?

Comment: Yes @Scott i have tried many times, but still nothing. No luck

Comment: On Linux you have to do `./gradlew` instead of just `gradlew`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : I am receiving message bash: ./gradlew: Permission denied

Comment: `chmod 755 gradlew` and try again. If you still have problems, edit your question with the output of `ls -l`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have used this command to set execution flag 
"chmod +x gradlew" and now i am able to apply this command " gradlew --refresh-dependencies".

Comment: @Paul "Please note that the command has to be executed within the terminal available in Android studio, not from Command Prompt (PC) or terminal (mac)." Where did you read or learn this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127856/discussion-between-addy-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: Can you run your app from Android Studio now?

Comment: Same issue, gradle is running ( 6 minutes ) don't know how much more time to wait.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are running the refresh dependencies task. You need to run the `build` task probably after a `clean`.

Comment: @cricket_007: When i run build after clean it keeps running.

Comment: In the terminal, or in Android Studio? I might suggest downloading Gradle with apt get and using that instead of the Gradle wrapper

Comment: Well finally i solve this issue by uninstalling android studio and re-installing android studio without installing Noguat. I have tried almost all commands, don't know through which command it is solved. but  yes i am lucky now i can run my app. :D